# How to install Internet Explorer on Mac OS X 10.11.6 ( EL Captain OS )?

Tags: macos, internet-explorer

How to install Internet Explorer on Mac OS X 10.11.6 ( EL Captain OS ) ?

Comment: Some minimal research would show this is not possible

Answer (score 4):

IE hasnt' been available for Mac since version 5.x. Your best depends on your needs: cheap PC, Virtual PC, Parallels, different browser on Mac.

What are you trying to accomplish - what need do you have for IE on Mac?

Comment: I have to use RDP  ( RD Webaccess ) to connect my work computer from Home.

Comment: How does needing RDP mean you need IE? MS RDP is a separate product.

Comment: Tetsujin is correct. Remote Desktop Connection app is installed with MS Office on Mac. That, or other 3rd party tools, can be used to connect remotely from your Mac to view your Windows desktop - whether a server or an actual PC. You will need the IP or Machine name (if on a local network), access granted by your IT or specifically on the Windows machine, and, the login and pw for that Windows machine. You mention your work computer. What I've typed may or may not be permitted depending on the company. It's set company by company. You should check with your work IT for additional instructions.

Comment: @CDK, I am thinking of purchasing Portable Desktop - Windows.(HP Elite). My question is, If i have a Portable Desktop , using Remote Desktop App in Macbook, will it be possible for me to remote login ..

Comment: You should be able to, but for less technical people, I use https://www.teamviewer.com/en/

Answer (score 2):

The last native version of Internet Explorer for Mac was IE5, in about 2003.

There are two ways to run a more current version

1. using a VM running Windows, or
2. this intriguing way to run it using MS Remote Desktop Connection & the Azure RemoteApp - admirably explained by [OSXDaily](http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/19/use-internet-explorer-11-mac-os-x-easy/) - too much for me to précis here & not something I can test, as the current RDC beta no longer has the Azure tab.